How Would I Break the Molecular Bonds of A Fictional Polar Atom
My world itself revolves around and adheres to real world physics, chemistry, biology, etc., with one difference, a fictional atom.
This atom, which we will call X Atom/Matter as a placeholder, is an atom that enables what I call, "kinesis", which is shorthand for atomic manipulation. To elaborate, the atom has 3 properties that enable this;

X Atoms are composed of Baryonic subatomic particles.
X Atoms, when in a molecular bond, are extremely polar.
X Atoms can form and break molecular bonds far more easily than that of a regular atom.

All these properties thus enable "kinesis". Because as the formation and breaking of molecular bonds generates electric fields, by rapidly toggle polarity on and off, the polarity should exert torque causing molecules to be pushed into alignment with the field. This should effectively fling the pair in opposite directions along your field lines. So I think this allows one to effectively create pressure in either direction aligned with the field and negative pressure (since the atoms flying away from the center will leave fewer particles in the middle of the field).*
The problem arises in completing this. I already have the current subatomic composition that enables polarity in these atoms, as their protons and electrons would consist of 2 Up and 1 Down particle alongside 1 Up and Down particle respectively, but I am struggling to come up with any potential solution that enables such molecular bonds to also break to enable electromagnetic field generation.
If anyone could potentially offer any solution, I would be glad to listen.
(*)Note: Breaking the bonds and forming bonds with polar and non-polar atoms respectively can be initially difficult as resistance does occur when attempting to do so, just to clarify.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Don't point 1 and point 2 seem to pose a contradiction?

You need to understand the particles you're using better if you want to reach valid conclusions about them. This seems to be just word-salad using physics vocabulary at present, and that's no basis for reasoning.

@Escapeddentalpatient. Honestly the list itself is fine. Adjusting a little vocabulary to avoid category errors: baryonic, tend to form polar molecules, and always bonding and re-bonding with everything it meets... sounds like a H+ or D+ ion to me.

OP, there is no way to do what you want to do short of getting a few physics PhDs and then spending the first twenty thousand pages of your novel guiding all your readers through a master's degree in fake wrong physics instead of writing a story. I'd suggest picking whatever actual plot-relevant problems, capabilities, and constraints you want your characters to encounter and not worrying about physics except to give some of the capabilities and constraints physics-y names like "Brannigan diminution" and "Zaphod's theorem".

If this actually worked, wouldn't we see it in the real world? So no, since it isn't real then on some level it won't make realistic sense. That's fine. You're writing fiction, you're allowed to make things up.

@gs "Sounds like an H+ ion to me" I've heard free radicals proposed as the solution for everything else from rocketry to biosciences, so why not telekinesis?

@ChristopherWells. I appreciate the constructive criticism, but I do have to say that kind of logic is a bit constructive? Like, yes, X Atoms don't exist in the real world. But what about most attempts at taking something fantastical, like a dragon, and attempting it to make abide by real physics, chemistry, and biology. I am just trying to push that idea at its furthest extent. But I will say that yes, even such attempts to turn something fantastical will obviously not be completely realistic, and I do appreciate the suggestion. Same goes to everyone here. Thx fr the ideas.

Something like this does exist, (polar composite atoms) it's called picoscale hydrogen chemistry and those bonds are not easy to pluck apart. Read some papers from Jacques DuFour, a good concept to integrate into a story!

giving a link only is not what we consider an answer: once the link goes dead (which is rather common) this won't give any information, while an answer shall stand on its own. Please add the relevant part of the link in the answer, while keeping the citation.

Can you clarify your scenario please: Do you want the outside field to be the cause of the "kinesis" thus: molecules can be "transformed" into other matter because of the field influence? Or is it like: The X atoms are the cause why molecules can rearrange themselves and the field is created because of the splitting of the molecule? Is the field created by a human somehow to transform or manipulate matter? Or is it only possible with a machine that creates that field and once the field is gone the kinesis properties are gone?

Important thing is that such atoms has to be somehow controlled. You inject a lot of X atom into a glass of water. You want to convert it to hidrogen-peroxide and hidrogen gas. How do you want to control to the X atoms, what should they do? How do you say to the X atoms, "now break up an O-H bond, now break up another, now glue these by their O atoms"? If you just inject a very polar atoms into the water, you will get a solution and that was it.

@Antares To answer your question (I apologize, as I was aware for a long time), the scenario would be the latter for the first question, as it is the X atoms being launched into opposite directions due to the constant forming and breaking of bonds that creates the field in question. As for the 2nd question, the answer is both. The field does enable a human to manipulate matter (though not transform outside of states, so no alchemical transmutation), but once the field is gone, the kinetic properties are not strong enough to enable kinesis.

Your problem arises because of bonds between X atom and regular molecules. So here are some ideas:

If X atoms are part of a molecule, the molecular properties change so that X atoms properties take precedence. In fact the subatomic particles in the molecule synchronize to the spin properties of the X atom(s) being part of it. Thus the same forces that govern X atoms to split and form magnetic fields can also influence the bonding inside molecules.

Your world could be enhanced to not just introduce a certain, single, distinct form of X atoms but rather introduce a certain configuration of subatomic particles which are inherent to each and every existing atom. This way the X atom properties apply to any atom and you can explain the forming of electric fields as "usual" and the special "kinesis" as you described as well.

X atoms are able to immitate regular matter. Meaning: X atoms can form bonds and molecular configurations just as atoms of that certain matter do. But they are "metamorph" thus can change this configuration also by rearranging protons and electrons between the X atom nuclea. In fact water (H2O) could be transformed into similar matter like HeO and other configurations which keep the number of Protons and Neutrons the same. This would of course imply that there is "regular" water lacking the kinesis properties and there is "metamorphic" kinesis-enabled water consisting solely of X atoms.


